# How to show a show default image if image not exist in database ASP.NET CORE 3.1

Tags: c#, asp.net-core

How to show a show default image if image not exist in database ASP.NET CORE 3.1

I tried this. not working because i save it as array of bytes and this is a path "string"

<img class="masthead-avatar mb-5" src="~/img/@Model.Owner.Avatar ?? "images/defaultImage.jpg"" style="border-radius:50%" alt="">

Comment: Hi @MohanedGermany, any updates about this case?

Answer (score 0):

This is wrong because source `~/img/@Model.Owner.Avatar` .. only browser know if image not exist.

You need do check on server side.

In your cshml you can do

```
@{
    var avatarImg = File.Exists($"~/img/{Model.Owner.Avatar}") ? "$"~/img/{Model.Owner.Avatar}" : "images/defaultImage.jpg";
}
```

and later

```
<img class="masthead-avatar mb-5" src="@avatarImg" style="border-radius:50%" alt="">
```

Answer (score 0):

Or another option would be to do it client-side, through the onerror event:

```
<img src="..." onerror="this.src = 'default.jpg'" />
```

Answer (score 0):

> How to show a show default image if image not exist in database ASP.NET CORE 3.1

> I tried this. not working because i save it as array of bytes and this is a path "string"

If you save image file as binary data into database directly, to display it in your view page, you can try to convert Byte Array into a base64 string first, like below.

```
<img class="masthead-avatar mb-5" src="@(Model.Owner.Avatar == null ? "/img/default.jpg" : string.Format("data:image/jpg;base64,{0}",Convert.ToBase64String(Model.Owner.Avatar)))" style="border-radius:50%" alt="">
```